# Java JsonPath length of array

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot, jsonpath

I have a Json like this:

```
{
    "hello": {
        "hello": [
            {
                "wwrjgn": "aerg",
                "aaa": "gggg",
                "rfshs": {
                    "segse": "segsegs",
                    "xx": "rgwgwgw",
                    "x-e ": "eergye"
                },
                "egg": "sgsese",
                "segess": "sgeses",
                "segess": "segess"
            },
            {
                "esges": "segesse",
                "segesg": "ws",
                "rddgdr": {
                    "rdrdrdg": “srgsesees"
                },
                "drr": 3600,
                "esese": "uytk",
                "wew": "699",
                "eses": “qe4ty"
            }
        ],
        "how": www"
    }
}
```

I do the following:

```
Object document = 
Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions().jsonProvider()
            .parse(ka.toJSONString());
int queries = JsonPath.read(document, "$..hello.length()");

    System.out.println("THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES " + queries);
```

I get:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray 
cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to 
java.base/java.lang.Integer
```

Trying it here: http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..hello.length()
I get:

```
[
   2,
   2
]
```

Which is what i need.

Any idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the exception say: you use incompatible types. You cannot convert a `JSONArray` (which seems to be the result o fthe `JsonPath.read(...)` method) into an `Integer`.

Comment: @Turing85 When I do JSONArray = instead of int = i get: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Comment: Try List<String> or List<Integer> as a return value

Comment: Well... this is expected if you use two different `JSONArray` classes.

Comment: @Guts now I don't get exceptions, but for both cases I get: THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES [ ]

Comment: i.e. it basically isn't throwing exception now but still not working :(

Comment: Did you check value of document? Maybe there is something wrong with parsing json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

```
JsonPath.read(document, "$..hello.length()")
```

... will cast its response  an instance of `net.minidev.json.JSONArray` which cannot be cast to an `int`. This explains the `ClassCastException`

The reason you see ...

```
[
   2,
   2
]
```

... when trying the online evaulator is that this is the `toString()` for the `JSONArray` instance returns that String.

To get the "THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES " in code, just read the JsonPath output as a `JSONArray` and then get the size attribute of that type. For example:

```
JSONArray read = JsonPath.read(document, "$..hello.length()");
// prints:
//    THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES 2
System.out.println("THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES " + read.size());
```

You could also return a `List<Integer`, for example:

```
List<Integer> read = JsonPath.read(document, "$..hello.length()");
// prints:
//    THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES 2
System.out.println("THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES " + read.size());
```

Comment: Your answer is semantically sound, but there seems to be a cultrip: OP seems to import a different `JSONArray` class ( `org.json.simple.JSONArray`). You may want to use the FQDN in this case (see the comment section of the question for details).

Comment: I get the following exception now: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Comment: The exception is thrown at JSONArray read = JsonPath.read(document, "$..hello.length()");

Comment: @Turing85 Ive used jsonpath before for actually parsing through and reading and those work.. its just the array length that doesnt work.. Not sure if that matters though

Comment: @user6671584 I have updated the answer to address the confusion between the types of `JSONArray`. As @Turing85 said, you could use the FQDN (`net.minidev.json.JSONArray`) or just use a `List<Integer>` like I show in my latest update.

Comment: @glytching yes and I tried both.. (I prefer not changing the FQDN) but both give THE LENGTH OF THE NUMBER OF QUERIES 0
:(

Comment: @user6671584 I took the code from your question and ran it locally - with the modification shown in my answer - and it produced your desired result so it looks like your question is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @glytching your List<Integer> solution is correct.. Im dumb, was also doing something else wrong when reading the document as Guts suggested. Thank you both.